Can't run basic commands on MacOS after running a wrong command
I wanted to locate my zsh in my /usr/local/bin directory on my mac using the command:
ll | grep zsh

But I accidently type
ll | zsh

and now when I try to run command lit
git status

or
pip --version

it either tells me the exec format error or simply does nothing. Even brew update does not do nothing, not even printing an error message.
I tried restarting my mac and my shell. I checked the the PATH variable is good. What can I do?

You have likely overwritten you ~/.zshrc (default location) config file.
If you haven't made any changes in the default, you should be able to just reinstall Z-shell to restore it.
But if you had many customized stuff it it, I would check if you have a backup on that file either via Time Machine or the Cloud solution, and the replace the file with the one from the backup data.
